# changing Panel Template depending of datatype

Tags: wpf

i've got a treeview (on the left) and wrappanel (on the right). The Treeview display content from XMLDataProvider the XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Documents>
  <DocFolder Name="Folder">
    <DocFolder DocFolderName="Subfolder">
      <DocItem DocItemName="item" />
    </DocFolder>
  </DocFolder>
</Documents>
```

Is it possible to display different content in WrapPanel binded to TreeView selected Item `{Binding ElementName=treeView1, Path=SelectedItem}` depending on the type of element that is selected (DocFolder or DocItem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that maybe ?

```
<Control DataContext="{Binding ElementName=treeView1, Path=SelectedItem}"
         Template="{Binding ElementName=treeView1, Path=SelectedItem,
                Converter={StaticResource selectedItemToDataTemplateConverter}}" />
```

... and the converter's code :

```
public class SelectedItemToDataTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                                         CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is DocFolder)
        {
           return new DocFolderUC(); // Your user control to display DocFolders..
        }
        else if (value is DocItem)
        {
           return new DocItemUC(); // Your user control to display DocItems..
        }
        [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you bound the warp pannel to the DataContext of the selected TreeView item, and used two typed DataTemplates to automatically display different content? I.e. `{Binding ElementName=treeView1, Path=SelectedItem.DataContext}`

Comment: Can WrapPanel have DataTemplate? I thought it is only for lists etc.